# determinant of the linear transformation $T(X) =\frac{1}{2} (AX+XA)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, determinant, linear-transformations

Let $V$ vector space of all matrices $3\times3$, and let $A$ be the diagonal matrix :

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &  0 & 0\\
0  &  2& 0 \\
0  &  0& 1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Compute thee determinant of the linear transformation $T(X) =\frac{1}{2} (AX+XA)$.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried computing its matrix (relative to the standard basis $(E_{i,j})$)?

Comment: Note that $AX$ is the matrix $X$ with the second row doubled.  Similarly $XA$ is the matrix $X$ with the second column doubled.  This can help you compute the matrix $T(X)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that your transformation is realized by a $9\times 9 $ matrix, as $X$ has $9$ elements.

So 
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x_{11} \\
x_{12} \\
x_{13} \\
x_{21} \\
x_{22} \\
x_{23} \\
x_{31} \\
x_{32} \\
x_{33}
\end{matrix}
\right) \quad\longmapsto\quad 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x_{11} \\
\tfrac{3}{2}x_{12} \\
x_{13} \\
\tfrac{3}{2}x_{21} \\
2x_{22} \\
\tfrac{3}{2}x_{23} \\
x_{31} \\
\tfrac{3}{2}x_{32} \\
x_{33}
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
and this is realized by the $9\times 9$ diagonal matrix
$$
T=\mathrm{diag}\,(1,\tfrac{3}{2},1,\tfrac{3}{2},2,\tfrac{3}{2},1,\tfrac{3}{2},1).
$$
Clearly $\det T=1\times\tfrac{3}{2}\times 1\times\tfrac{3}{2}\times2\times\tfrac{3}{2}\times1\times\tfrac{3}{2}\times1$

Comment: Just as I said...

Comment: @@Yiorgos S. Smyrlis) Can you please tell me how you got the diagonal entries of $T$ ? I can find it by finding $T$ with standard basis but that is very laborious.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Find the matrix  of the linear transformation.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the eigenvalues of $T$ are the pairwise averages of the eigenvalues of $A.$

Comment: @@Igor Rivin) Can you please tell me how it is the average ? I really don't understand anything your hint as well as the accepted answer .